# Preform multiple preg_replace inside matched text

Tags: php, regex

If there is a comma and a space inside a pair of square brackets, I'm trying to replace it with a closing square bracket and an opening square bracket.

Basically, I have a block of text that looks like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi laoreet 
lobortis blandit. Proin in nulla mauris.[3, 8, 19, 45] Aenean dictum 
sollicitudin nibh, non semper mauris semper id.[52, 58] Donec at varius eros. 
Sed in risus nec tellus vehicula semper. In id elit vel nunc ornare faucibus. 
Integer feugiat erat mauris, in tempus leo imperdiet ac.[23]
```

That I'm trying to make look like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi laoreet 
lobortis blandit. Proin in nulla mauris.[3][8][19][45] Aenean dictum 
sollicitudin nibh, non semper mauris semper id.[52][58] Donec at varius eros. 
Sed in risus nec tellus vehicula semper. In id elit vel nunc ornare faucibus. 
Integer feugiat erat mauris, in tempus leo imperdiet ac.[23]
```

I wrote a `preg_replace` function but it only performs the replacement if it exists one time inside the bracket set:

```
$output = preg_replace("/(\[\d*), (\d*\])/", "$1][$2", $input);
```

How can I modify my regex so it will perform multiple replacements inside the matched text?

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this easily with a positive look behind so it might be easier to just extract all the bracket sets in a preg_match_all, apply the translation to each result, and replace them back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way would be:

```
, (?=[^][]*\])
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/w10Lbd/1)

Breakdown:

- `,[ ]` Match a comma following a space character
- `(?=` Start of a positive lookahead

  - `[^][]*\]` Assert whether it follows a closing bracket without matching a bracket
- `)` End of lookahead

PHP code:

```
echo preg_replace('/, (?=[^][]*\])/', '][', $str);
```

But if it's likely to have a closing bracket somewhere in text without being opened, this is more bulletproof:

```
(?:\[(?=[^][]*\])|\G(?!\A))[^],]*\K,
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/SCyC1T/1)

Comment: could you plz explain how this positive lookahead works only for digits inside bracket and it doesn't match characters after `, `?

Comment: Sure. It doesn't work for digits only. It doesn't look for specific characters but it looks for an upcoming closing bracket `]` without matching a bracket in between. I wrote a breakdown. Please see.